# I was trying ti set up presto with azure gen2 , but facing the below issue when I am querying

Tags: azure, java, hive

I am using `prestodb:0.234`

Dependency jars:

```
   azure-storage-2.0.0.jar
   hadoop-azure-3.2.1.jar
   hadoop-azure-datalake-3.2.1.jar 
   azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.8.jar
```

I am getting below error while doing the querying.

```
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: cannot create caching file system
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration.lambda$getConfiguration$0(HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration.java:70)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration$CachingJobConf.createFileSystem(HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.get(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.lambda$getFileSystem$0(HdfsEnvironment.java:73)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.authentication.NoHdfsAuthentication.doAs(NoHdfsAuthentication.java:23)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:72)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:66)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadPartition(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:298)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.loadSplits(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:270)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.access$300(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:100)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.BackgroundHiveSplitLoader$HiveSplitLoaderTask.process(BackgroundHiveSplitLoader.java:199)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.safeProcessTask(ResumableTasks.java:47)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks.access$000(ResumableTasks.java:20)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks$1.run(ResumableTasks.java:35)
    at com.facebook.airlift.concurrent.BoundedExecutor.drainQueue(BoundedExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.createFileSystem(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.getInternal(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.PrestoFileSystemCache.get(PrestoFileSystemCache.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration.lambda$getConfiguration$0(HiveCachingHdfsConfiguration.java:66)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`ABFS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver) mentioned in the stacktrace as a caching filesystem, then I suppose two possible reasons and suggest solutions for them

### Dependency mesh in `maven`

As noted in two answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118824/5720818), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532248/5720818)) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265002/hadoop-no-filesystem-for-scheme-file)

> When we use maven-assembly-plugin, it merges all our JARs into one, and all META-INFO/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem overwrite each-other. Only one of these files remains (the last one that was added). In this case, the FileSystem list from hadoop-commons overwrites the list from hadoop-hdfs, so DistributedFileSystem was no longer declared.

So, check your dependencies and if there are `JAR` with correct `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` in your distibution.

### `PrestoDB` uses outdated `azure-site.xml`

There is [known issue #11648](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/11648). 
And as [said](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/11648#issuecomment-522853533), `ABFS`, `ADLS` and `ALDS gen2` was only introduced to https://github.com/prestosql/presto, not to `prestodb`

So, suggestion is to ask your question on [Presto Community Slack](https://prestosql.io/community.html)

## P.S. try `storediag`

There is a `hadoop` manual on `Azure` [ABFS](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/745a6c1e69b3699f6496a146afc48824dd735461/hadoop-tools/hadoop-azure/src/site/markdown/abfs.md)

And among other tips [they recommend](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/745a6c1e69b3699f6496a146afc48824dd735461/hadoop-tools/hadoop-azure/src/site/markdown/abfs.md):

> One useful tool for debugging connectivity is the [cloudstore storediag utility](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/releases).
>
> This validates the classpath, the settings, then tries to work with the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @Yasen , the above suggestions helped me lot to resolve my issue. First i shifted to prestosql and used respective jar versions resolved my problem